# R.string.gamehelper_unknown_error cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm suppose to fix this code that my friend bought from some site chupamobile and it's written in mainly c++ using cocos2d-x but my problem seems to be with the java-files.

[This file](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelperUtils.java), `GameHelperUtils.java`, looks just as the original you get with cocos2d-x 
But I got this error to 4 variables inside R.string, you can see it in this picture below:
[image]

I see that `R.string` seems to be accessible and the R-files that sometimes eclipse has problem creating seems to be there. I'm no sure which of them is used though.

Comment: can you post your code by text and not link to some projects?

Comment: first of all, check if right R is imported, secondly see res/string.xml for this strings

Comment: I didn't see any of them in the res/values/strings.xml but when I added them the error disappeared.. Dunno if I should have done it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done the following

- Included necessary XML files
- They all compile ok
- That you include R class in your class
- Eclipse is dumb and needs a lot of clean and build cycles. Most of the time, this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't prepend "gamemaker" to the R.string variables. You can see how they're defined from [this](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/res/values/strings.xml) file. So Change that line to:

```
private final static int[] RES_IDS = {
    R.string.unkown_error, R.string.sign_in_failed, 
    R.string.app_misconfigured, R.string.license_failed
};
```

If, on the other hand, they've already be redefined, look in your local res/values folder to see what the variables are defined as in strings.xml.